# setAccessToken on embedded dashboard instance doesn't work initially

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I'm using the [PowerBi-Javascript library](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript) to embed a powerBI dashboard:

```
let embedConfig = {
  type: 'dashboard',
  tokenType: window.powerbi-client.models.TokenType.Aad,
  id: '...',
  embedUrl: '...',
  accessToken: '...'
};
let embedInstance = powerbi.embed(elem, embedConfig);
```

Later I want to update the access token to ensure the dashboard can keep updating its data. We use the following approach:

```
embedInstance.setAccessToken('...')
.then(function (r) {
  console.log('New access token set succesfully');
})
.catch(function (e) {
  console.error('Error setting access token', e);
});
```

The `setAccessToken` promise resolves (I see the success log), however, I'm not certain that the access token is correctly propagated to the PowerBI instance.

What I find is that the next time the data on the embedded dashboard updates, I get a 401 response logged in the console for a request to `https://wabi-uk-south-redirect.analysis.windows.net/powerbi/metadata/dashboards/[my-id]`.

If I subsequently refresh the data (before the access token expires again), everything seems to work fine.

It seems that *the first data refresh after a new access token is set over an expired one* fails.

This is a big problem for me because the data we have refreshes (automatically) less frequently than the access token expires, so after the first access token expires, the data never refreshes in my embedded instance.

Has anyone else had this problem, or does anyone know of a way around this?

**UPDATE:** 
The requests that fail are always to `/powerbi/metadata/dashboards/[my-id]`, whereas requests that work and cause the data to refresh are to `/powerbi/metadata/dashboards/[my-id]/tiles`. Note that I am not triggering these refreshes programatically, just by going to the powerbi web app (app.powerbi.com) and clicking "Refresh dashboard tiles".

Comment: Hey, I am also facing the similar issue. Do you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

a call to /powerbi/metadata/dashboards/[my-id] happens only on dashboard load to get the dashboard metadata.
It is NOT the best practice to embed a dashboard with a near expiry token.
In order to embed a dashboad make sure the AAD token you have does have few minutes until expiry.

Calls to sync service which update the tiles size and position and tile data are working OK.

In addition, in your application, set a timer which updates the token few minutes before expiry, this will make your dashboard more "live", because if the sync service fails with un-authorized exceptions few times, it goes into a sleep for almost 30 seconds.

please let me know if that helps.